# Timeout manager with PriorityQueue

Tags: java

[image: I'm stuck on the last part of this lab for my java class.]

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LabProgram {
    public static boolean verifyCallbacks(PrintWriter testFeedback, ArrayList<String> actual,
            ArrayList<String> expected) {
        // Compare ArryList sizes first
        boolean areEqual = true;
        if (actual.size() == expected.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; areEqual && i < actual.size(); i++) {
                if (!actual.get(i).equals(expected.get(i))) {
                    areEqual = false;
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            areEqual = false;
        }

        // Print results
        testFeedback.write(areEqual ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
        testFeedback.write(": Verification of invoked callbacks\n");
        testFeedback.write("  Expected: " + expected + "\n");
        testFeedback.write("  Actual:   " + actual + "\n");
        return areEqual;
    }

    public static boolean test1(PrintWriter testFeedback) {
        TestClock clock = new TestClock();
        TimeoutManager timeouts = new TimeoutManager(clock);

        ArrayList<String> actualCallbacks = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> expectedCallbacks = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Test with items:
        // Added at clock time = 0:
        // - item D with delay 500 (callback time is 500)
        // - item A with delay 100 (callback time is 100)
        // Added at clock time = 50
        // - item B with delay 150 (callback time is 200)
        clock.setTime(0);
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("D");
            testFeedback.write("Item D's callback\n");
        }, 500);
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("A");
            testFeedback.write("Item A's callback\n");
        }, 100);
        clock.setTime(50);
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("B");
            testFeedback.write("Item B's callback\n");
        }, 150);

        // Do an update with clock time = 100, which should invoke item A's
        // callback
        clock.setTime(100);
        testFeedback.write("Updating with clock time = 100. Item A should show below.\n");
        timeouts.update();

        // Verify that only item A's callback was called
        expectedCallbacks.add("A");
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do another update with a clock time of 150, which shouldn't invoke any
        // callbacks
        clock.setTime(150);
        testFeedback.write("Updating with clock time = 150. No callbacks should show below.\n");
        timeouts.update();

        // Verify that still only item A's callback has been called
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Add more timeouts at clock time = 300:
        // - item E with delay 500 (callback time is 800)
        // - item C with delay 100 (callback time is 400)
        clock.setTime(300);
        testFeedback.write("Adding timeouts E and C\n");
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("E");
            testFeedback.write("Item E's callback\n");
        }, 500);
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("C");
            testFeedback.write("Item C's callback\n");
        }, 100);

        // Verify that adding new timeouts didn't invoke any new callbacks
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do an update with a clock time of 350, which should invoke item B's
        // callback
        clock.setTime(350);
        testFeedback.write("Updating with clock time = 350. Item B should show below.\n");
        timeouts.update();

        // Verify callbacks: A and B called, others not
        expectedCallbacks.add("B");
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do an update with a clock time of 550, which should invoke item C's
        // callback and item D's callback, in that order
        clock.setTime(550);
        testFeedback.write("Updating with clock time = 550. Item C and D should show below, ");
        testFeedback.write("in that order.\n");
        timeouts.update();

        // Verify callbacks: A, B, C, and D
        expectedCallbacks.add("C");
        expectedCallbacks.add("D");
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do another update with a clock time of 700, which shouldn't invoke any
        // callbacks
        clock.setTime(700);
        testFeedback.write("Updating with clock time = 700. No callbacks should show below.\n");
        timeouts.update();

        // Verify callbacks: again just A, B, C, and D
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do a final update with time = 900, which should invoke item E's callback
        clock.setTime(900);
        testFeedback.write("Updating with clock time = 900. Item E should show below.\n");
        timeouts.update();

        // Verify callbacks: A, B, C, D, and E
        expectedCallbacks.add("E");
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean test2(PrintWriter testFeedback) {
        TestClock clock = new TestClock();
        TimeoutManager timeouts = new TimeoutManager(clock);

        ArrayList<String> actualCallbacks = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> expectedCallbacks = new ArrayList<String>();

        // At t = 0:
        // - Add item A with delay 800 (callback time is 800)
        clock.setTime(0);
        testFeedback.write("At t=0, adding timeout A with delay = 800\n");
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("A");
        }, 800);

        // At t = 50:
        // - Add item D with delay 600 (callback time is 650)
        clock.setTime(50);
        testFeedback.write("At t=50, adding timeout D with delay = 600\n");
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("D");
        }, 600);

        // At t = 100:
        // - Add item C with delay 200 (callback time is 300)
        clock.setTime(100);
        testFeedback.write("At t=100, adding timeout C with delay = 200\n");
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("C");
        }, 200);

        // At t = 150:
        // - Add item E with delay 250 (callback time is 400)
        clock.setTime(150);
        testFeedback.write("At t=150, adding timeout E with delay = 250\n");
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("E");
        }, 250);

        // At t = 200:
        // - Add item B with delay 50 (callback time is 250)
        // - Update, then verify that no callback have yet been called
        clock.setTime(200);
        testFeedback.write("At t=200, adding timeout B with delay = 50");
        testFeedback.write(", then updating\n");
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("B");
        }, 50);
        timeouts.update();
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // At t = 400:
        // - Update, then verify that callbacks B, C, and E have been called
        clock.setTime(400);
        testFeedback.write("At t=400, updating\n");
        timeouts.update();
        expectedCallbacks.add("B");
        expectedCallbacks.add("C");
        expectedCallbacks.add("E");
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // At t = 450:
        // - Add item F with delay 100 (callback time is 550)
        clock.setTime(450);
        testFeedback.write("At t=450, adding timeout F with delay = 100\n");
        timeouts.addTimeout(() -> {
            actualCallbacks.add("F");
        }, 100);

        // At t = 600:
        // - Update, then verify callbacks: B and C from earlier, E and F now
        clock.setTime(600);
        testFeedback.write("At t=600, updating\n");
        timeouts.update();
        expectedCallbacks.add("F");
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        // At t = 800:
        // - Update, then verify callbacks: B, C, E, F, D, A
        clock.setTime(800);
        testFeedback.write("At t=800, updating\n");
        timeouts.update();
        expectedCallbacks.add("D");
        expectedCallbacks.add("A");
        if (!verifyCallbacks(testFeedback, actualCallbacks, expectedCallbacks)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter testFeedback = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        boolean test1Result = test1(testFeedback);
        testFeedback.println();

        boolean test2Result = test2(testFeedback);
        testFeedback.println();

        testFeedback.flush();

        System.out.println("Local test 1: " + (test1Result ? "PASS" : "FAIL"));
        System.out.println("Local test 2: " + (test2Result ? "PASS" : "FAIL"));
        
        testFeedback.close();
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class MillisecondClock {
    abstract int getTime();
}
```

```
public class TestClock extends MillisecondClock {
    private int currentTime;

    public TestClock() {
        currentTime = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTime() {
        return currentTime;
    }

    // Sets this clock's current time, provided the new time is greater than the
    // previously set time.
    public boolean setTime(int newTime) {
        // Only allow time to move forward
        if (newTime > currentTime) {
            currentTime = newTime;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CallbackMethod {
    void invoke();
}

public class TimeoutItem implements Comparable<TimeoutItem> {
    private int callbackTime;
    private CallbackMethod callbackMethod;

    public TimeoutItem(CallbackMethod callbackMethod, int callbackTime) {
        this.callbackTime = callbackTime;
        this.callbackMethod = callbackMethod;
    }

    public TimeoutItem(TimeoutItem toCopy) {
        this.callbackTime = toCopy.callbackTime;
        this.callbackMethod = toCopy.callbackMethod;
    }

    public void callCallback() {
        callbackMethod.invoke();
    }

    final public int getCallbackTime() {
        return callbackTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TimeoutItem tItem) {
       // Java's PriorityQueue keeps item with smallest value at the front.
        if (this.callbackTime > tItem.callbackTime) {
            return 1;
        } 
        else if (this.callbackTime < tItem.callbackTime) {
            return -1;
        } 
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class TimeoutManager {
   private PriorityQueue<TimeoutItem> queue;
   private MillisecondClock clock;
   
   public TimeoutManager(MillisecondClock clock) {
      this.queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
      this.clock = clock;
   }
   
   public void addTimeout(Runnable callback, int delayBeforeCallback) {
      int callbackTime = clock.getTime() + delayBeforeCallback;
      TimeoutItem item = new TimeoutItem(callback, callbackTime);
      queue.offer(item);
   }
   
   public void update() {
      int currentTime = clock.getTime();
      while (!queue.isEmpty() && queue.peek().getCallbackTime() <= currentTime) {
         TimeoutItem item = queue.poll();
         item.getCallbackMethod().run();
      }
   }
}
```

This is my code so far but I keep getting error:

TimeoutManager.java:14: error: incompatible types: Runnable cannot be converted to CallbackMethod
TimeoutItem item = new TimeoutItem(callback, callbackTime);
^
TimeoutManager.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
item.getCallbackMethod().run();
^
symbol:   method getCallbackMethod()
location: variable item of type TimeoutItem
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors

I know I have to do something in the last part but I'm stuck. Please help

Comment: The constructor of your `TimeoutItem` class is `TimeoutItem(CallbackMethod callbackMethod, int callbackTime)`, but you invoke it as `new TimeoutItem(someRunnable, someInt)`. A `Runnable` isn't a `CallbackMethod` and cannot be assigned to one. If you want to convert, you could use a method reference to convert between the two SAM types: `new TimeoutItem(someRunnable::run, someInt)` (because `Runnable#run` is signature-compatible with `CallbackMethod#invoke`)

Answer (score -1):

TIMEOUT MANAGER.PY should look something like this:

import sys
from queue import PriorityQueue

from TimeoutItem import TimeoutItem
from Clocks import *

class TimeoutManager:
def **init**(self, clock):
# The current time used by the add_timeout() and update()
self.clock = clock
# A priority queue of TimeoutItems. The timeout item with the
# lowest callback time is the first to be dequeued.
self.pq = PriorityQueue()

```
# Return a timeout manager's internal priority queue.
# Used only for grading purposes.
def get_priority_queue(self):
    return self.pq

def get_priority_queue_times(self):
    return sorted([entry.get_callback_time() for entry in self.pq.queue])

# Add a TimeoutItem.
# The added timeout expires at:
#     (clock's current time when self function is called) + (item's delay time)
def add_timeout(self,
                delay_before_callback,
                callback):     
    current_time = self.clock.get_time() 
    callback_time = current_time + delay_before_callback 
    new_timeout_item = TimeoutItem(callback_time, callback) 
    self.pq.put(new_timeout_item) 
    pass

# Dequeues each expired TimeoutItem from the priority queue in order of their
# priority and calls each expired item's callback function.
def update(self):
    current_time = self.clock.get_time() 

    while not self.pq.empty():
        next_item = self.pq.get() 
        if next_item.get_callback_time() <= current_time:
            next_item.call_callback() 
        else:
            self.pq.put(next_item) 
            break
```